# List of variable names in Python 3.8

Tags: python, list, variables

In my program I have to handle large amounts of variables, and I have to execute same piece of code on each of them.

```
try:
    a1 = int(a1_txt.get())
except ValueError:
    try:
        a1 = int(str(a1_txt.get()) + "0")
    except ValueError:
        a1 = 1
        invalid += 1
if 0 < a1 < 10:
    pass
else:
    rang += 1

try:
    a2 = int(a2_txt.get())
except ValueError:
    try:
        a2 = int(str(a2_txt.get()) + "0")
    except ValueError:
        a2 = 1
        invalid += 1
if 0 < a2 < 10:
    pass
else:
    rang += 1
```

As you can see, both pieces of code are same, the only difference is that on the place of a1, there is a2 in second piece. The problem here is that I have these variables up to i9 so I would have to rewrite this piece of code 64 times each time changing just one number or letter. Obviously that would be dumb, there must be another way. Thanks for help in advance. Regards

Comment: I would suggest looking up `for` loops and functions

Comment: And lists as well.

Comment: I know about both of them, but I don't see how they would help me in this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a dictionary instead:

```
d = {1:int(a1_txt.get()),
     2:int(a2_txt.get())}

for k in d.keys():

    try:
        d[k] = int(a2_txt.get())
    except ValueError:
        try:
            d[k] = int(str(a2_txt.get()) + "0")
        except ValueError:
            d[k] = 1
            invalid += 1
    if 0 < d[k] < 10:
        pass
    else:
        rang += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer your question:

```
def reusable_code(text):
    try:
        a = int(text.get())
    except ValueError:
        try:
            a = int(str(text.get()) + "0")
        except ValueError:
            a = 1
            invalid += 1
    if 0 < a < 10:
        pass
    else:
        rang += 1
```

This can be reused 64 times if you iterate through the txt's and call this function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, this solves just one part of my problem, because I need variables a1, a2, a3, .... to be accessible later because I will need to form a list from them.

Comment: If you'd like, you can "return a" at the end of the code and declare a list with "list_ = []" then as you loop through the texts, you can run "list_.append(reusable_code(txt))"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `eval()` to find the value of a variable, given its `str` representation, 
or `exec()` for more advanced purposes:

```
a1,a2 = 8,4
for var_name in ("a1","a2"): # If there is some pattern to var_names, a double-loop here might help.
    if 0 < eval(var_name) < 10:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of your variables, and then use a for loop to iterate through them.

Assuming I've understood your situation correctly, the following should be a start:

```
def use_text(txt):
    try:
        a = int(txt.get())
    except ValueError:
        try:
            a = int(str(txt.get()) + "0")
        except ValueError:
            a = 1
        invalid += 1
    if 0 < a < 10:
        pass
    else:
        rang += 1

txts = [a1, a2, a3] #and so on
for i in txts:
    use_text(i)
```

There will almost certainly be a better solution than `a = [a1, a2, a3] #and so on`, but this will depend on the structure of your code and the data you're dealing with.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately, this solves just one part of my problem, because I need variables a1, a2, a3, .... to be accessible later because I will need to form a list from them.

Comment: That should be fine! the line `txts = [a1, a2, a3] #and so on` will store your variables in texts, which can be accessed later.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of the structure and the logic behind your code here so it would be helpful if you provide an input sample or like where will you get the text from.
But if I understood correctly, maybe this will help:

If you already know the number of variables you have (n) and you have a list that contains the text you'll use each time

```
def reusable_finction(n,text_list):
    dict = {}
    i = 1
    invalid = 0
    rang = 0
    while i <n+1:
        try:
            x = int(text_list[i-1].get())
        except ValueError:
            try:
                x = int(str(text_list[i-1].get()) + "0")
            except ValueError:
                x = 1
                invalid += 1
        if 0 < x < 10:
            pass
        else:
            rang += 1

        dict["a"+str(i)] = x
```

Comment: Looks promising, I'm going to try to implement this in my program and see if it will work.